DFS replication takes 3-4 minutes to show up
We are a school with a small on premise setup with 2019 AD servers, DFS servers, and a print server.  DFS has been working relatively well over the past few years (not fond of the long replication time when the occasional permission changes occur) until recently when we noticed that it takes several minutes for files to show up in Windows Explorer.  Going from DFS server A to DFS server B the files show up right away.  But going from DFS server B to DFS server A takes 3 to 4 minutes.  The interesting part is that when looking on the servers themselves in the share folder, the files replicate right away.  It just takes a long time to show up on staff desktops on Windows Explorer and we have had some files overwritten as a result.
I have a single namespace with two namespace servers.  I tried changing the Cache duration from 300 seconds to 30 seconds with no effect.  I have increased the quota because we have some large files but I wouldn't expect that to affect anything.  I have kept the rest of the configuration with the default values (from what I remember).
This is my first post, so if I am missing some details or should include anything else, please let me know.  Any help is appreciated.

The interesting part is that when looking on the servers themselves in the share folder, the files replicate right away. It just takes a long time to show up on staff desktops on Windows Explorer this looks like client-side caching of SMB shares. How exactly are those shares accessed by users?

Just noticed your comment.  They access the shares via a mapped drive \xxx.local\sharename\sharefolder.  Is that what you were looking for?

Try this: https://tachytelic.net/2019/12/disable-smb-client-side-caching/

I did try that on one machine and it did work!  Thank you!  I was looking for a group policy setting that would allow me to push this out to all machines but couldn't find one.

Looks like the problem is caused by SMB client-side caching, which can cause behaviours like the one experienced by the OP and like the one described here: https://tachytelic.net/2019/12/disable-smb-client-side-caching.
This caching can be disabled by creating a Registry value of type DWORD called DirectoryCacheLifetime in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters and setting it to zero.
Also documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/file-server.

I am going to mark this as something that fixed my issue.  Thank you!  But if anyone has any way to push out this change to all machines, that would be helpful.

If there is not a specific administrative template for this, you can use Group Policy Preferences to push out any Registry key you want.
